# Is there anyway to predict "No space left on device" for btrfs which occurs long before the device is full?

Tags: btrfs

It's possible that `btrfs` fails to write data due to error `No space left on device` even though a lot of disk space remains free (can be a lot of GBs dependending on the size of the device). Installers that want to run smooth and intuitively will check the available disk space and inform the user if the remaining space isn't sufficient. Is there any way to anticipate the `No space left on device` error for this situation?

This is better to be fixed in `btrfs`, but apparently a large design error

I'm using Linux 4.8.1 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

`btrfs fi show 'path'` or `btrfs fi usage 'path'`

Installer show how namy space is on disk and which amount  is required.